# How can I get the current width of a specific amount of columns

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, singularitygs

What I want to achieve is getting the width value (in percentage) of a specific amount of columns (based on the current context).

Is there a *grid helper* to do this (maybe `find-grid` function)? Could you provide an example on how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`column-span`](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/blob/1.x.x/stylesheets/singularitygs/math/_columns.scss) function will do just that.

`scss
.foo {
  // 3 column span, from the 1st column
  width: column-span(3, 1);`